# Optimization with concept drift, changing location of the optimum over time

Tags: optimization, bayesian-optimization, concept-drift

Is there any research/literature on the topic of optimization where the location of the optimum changes over time? Nonetheless I am interested in an optimal solution at any given time.

It's hard for me to find anything, maybe because I don't know the specific terms. I am especially interested in bayesian-optimization/model-based optimization.

In my prefered scenario the location of the optimum changes in a continuous way.

*Edit*:
To put my question more precise I imagine it like the following
At any moment $t$ I want to have the solution (or an approximal solution) for

$
x_t^* = \arg \min f_t(x)
$

We can assume that $f_t(x)$ is deterministic for a fixed $t$.
To find the optimization I can try various parameter for $x$ but I don't have any influence on the $t$ as the time continuously progresses.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad, as there are infinitely many reasons why the location of the optimum changes (time-varying parameters, random variables, restrictions, networks...) So it would be useful if you specify the problems. You could take a look at the subfields in [Cybernetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybernetics#Subdivisions_of_the_field) but the term is too over-arching IMO. Depending on your need, there are two subfields that may be helpful and please feel free to add more:

1. [Markov Decision Process (MDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) is a hot field of research Operations Research, where people study practical problems like time-dependent pricing, routing, resource distribution, etc. The basic assumption, as the name suggests, is Markov.
2. [Signal Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing) in Electrical Engineering contributes many theoretical results on the analysis of signals in a continuous fashion, and I find its math particularly welcome to people familiar with statistics.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. But the Wikipedia articles on Signal Processing and Cybernetics seem even broader then my question.
Regarding MDP I might see a connection although I assume that the "states" are observable in a way which is not the case for the scenario I had in mind.